# Cannot enumerate XML Tree via TXMLDocument

Tags: xml, delphi, txmldocument

I try to use TXMLDocument in Delphi to enumerate a XML file. But whenever I exit the ProcessFile procedure, there will be an "Access violation" exception.

I declare XMLFile as an interface object IXMLDocument, instead of TXMLDocument, and do not call free it manually.

Below is the code:

```
//  Invoke ProcessFile in the main app
ProcessFile('C:\Myfile.xlf', True);

//  Process the node recursively
procedure ProcessNode1(Node: IXMLNode);
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  if (Node.NodeName = 'trans-unit') then
  begin
    //  Process 'trans-unit'
  end
  else
    for Index := 0 to Node.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
      ProcessNode1(Node.ChildNodes[Index]);
end;

procedure ProcessFile(const SrcFileName: string; const FixMode: Boolean);
var
  XmlFile: IXMLDocument;
  MainNode, FileNode: IXMLNode;
  OriginalFileName, SrcLang, DstLang: string;
begin
  //  Initialize the COM, otherwise we cannot use MSXML
  CoInitialize(nil);

  //  Open the XML document
  XmlFile := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  try
    XmlFile.LoadFromFile(SrcFileName);
    //  XmlFile.Active := True;

    MainNode := XmlFile.DocumentElement;
    FileNode := MainNode.ChildNodes['file'];

    OriginalFileName := FileNode.GetAttribute('original');
    SrcLang := FileNode.GetAttribute('source-language');
    DstLang := FileNode.GetAttribute('target-language');

    //  Output the information
    //  If removing the following statement, then everything will be OK.
    Writeln(Format('Call TranslateFile. OriginFile: %s. SrcFile: %s. SrcLang: %s. DstLang: %s. FixMode: %s.',
          [OriginalFileName, ExtractFileName(SrcFileName), SrcLang, DstLang, BoolToStr(FixMode, True)]));

    //  Enumerate the DOM tree
    ProcessNode1(FileNode);
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

Blow is the XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2 xliff-core-1.2-transitional.xsd" xmlns:soluling="http://www.soluling.com">
  <file original="a.rc" source-language="en-US" target-language="bg-BG" datatype="plaintext">
    <body>
      <group id="String" datatype="winres">
        <group id="IDS_TEST">
          <trans-unit id="String.IDS_TEST1">
            <source>a</source>
            <target state="translated" state-qualifier="fuzzy-match">b</target>
            <soluling:datatype>string</soluling:datatype>
            <soluling:rowstatus>rsInUse</soluling:rowstatus>
          </trans-unit>
        </group>
      </group>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

Comment: You are still making the same mistake as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77122152/). You are not managing the lifetime of the `TXMLDocument` object correctly, so it is being freed prematurely. Did you read the [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument) yet? "*When TXMLDocument is created without an Owner, it behaves like an interfaced object. That is, when all references to its interface are released, the TXMLDocument instance is automatically freed*"

Comment: [The tag txmldocument even explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/txmldocument): "_Dangerous for novices! Read the documentation!_"

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I change the XMLFile to IXMLDocument, but when exiting ProcessFile, I still get Access violation error. I do NOT try to free it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `CoUninitialize()` while the `XmlFile` `MainNode`, and `FileNode` objects are still active, so the RTL can't release them properly when they go out of scope when `ProcessFile()` exits, hence the Access Violation.

You need to clear those references before unloading the COM library, eg:

```
procedure ProcessFile(const SrcFileName: string; const FixMode: Boolean);
var
  XmlFile: IXMLDocument;
  MainNode, FileNode: IXMLNode;
  ...
begin
  //  Initialize the COM, otherwise we cannot use MSXML
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    //  Open the XML document
    XmlFile := LoadXMLDocument(SrcFileName);
    try
      MainNode := XmlFile.DocumentElement;
      FileNode := MainNode.ChildNodes['file'];
      ...
    finally
      // ADD THIS!
      FileNode := nil;
      MainNode := nil;
      XmlFile := nil;
    end;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively, separate the loading/unloading of the COM library from your tree processing code, eg:

```
procedure DoProcessFile(const SrcFileName: string; const FixMode: Boolean);
var
  XmlFile: IXMLDocument;
  MainNode, FileNode: IXMLNode;
  ...
begin
  //  Open the XML document
  XmlFile := LoadXMLDocument(SrcFileName);
  MainNode := XmlFile.DocumentElement;
  FileNode := MainNode.ChildNodes['file'];
  ...
end;

procedure ProcessFile(const SrcFileName: string; const FixMode: Boolean);
begin
  //  Initialize the COM, otherwise we cannot use MSXML
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    DoProcessFile(SrcFileName, FixMode);
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I choose the 2nd option.